# django redirect test - AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 302 (expected 200)

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I can't get my test to accept the redirect works... I keep getting this error "AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 302 (expected 200)"

but the redirect working

logs

```
web_1  | [11/Oct/2020 12:41:33] "GET /calendar/5d8b6a0a-66b8-4909-bf8f-8616593d2663/update/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
web_1  | [11/Oct/2020 12:41:33] "GET /calendar/list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4076
```

Please can some advise where I am going wrong. I have tried using assertRedirects but this still doesn't pass

test.py

```
class EventTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.eventbooked = Event.objects.create(
            manage=self.user, 
            availability='Booked',
            start_time='2020-09-30 08:00:00+00:00',
            end_time='2020-09-30 17:00:00+00:00',
        )


    def test_event_update_redirect_if_booked_view(self):
        self.client.login(email='test_username@example.com', password='da_password')
        response = self.client.get(self.eventbooked.get_absolute_url_edit())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertContains(response, 'Update Availability')
```

view.py - this is where the redirect happens, this the object is excluded.

```
class CalendarEventUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model= Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name='calendar_update_event_form.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter(manage=self.request.user).exclude(availability='Booked')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(CalendarEventUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return redirect(reverse('calendar_list'))
```

models.py

```
    def get_absolute_url_edit(self):
        return reverse('calendar_event_detail_update', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion error is not your expectation failing.

- `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)` This passes just fine.
- `self.assertContains(response, 'Update Availability')` This however fails. Your response is a 302 response which doesn't have a content. In the actual example you gave:

  - `"GET /calendar/5d8b6a0a-66b8-4909-bf8f-8616593d2663/update/ HTTP/1.1" 302` -> You're trying to test the content in the response for this request whereas...
  - `"GET /calendar/list/ HTTP/1.1" 200` -> ... the content is in the response to this request.